# WordPress: How to make the 'Theme Options Page' appear on the 'Edit Page'?

Tags: wordpress

Just in case, here's what *Theme Options Pages* are in WordPress:

http://css.dzone.com/articles/how-create-theme-options-page

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to get the *Theme Options Page* of any WordPress theme to appear on the 'Edit Page' of WordPress. Does anyone know how to do this so each page I create would have different results when published?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is that really WordPress is setup to have a single theme with a single set of options, what your trying to do is essentially have a new theme for each page.

Instead, you probably need individual [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) for those options that you would like to customize on a page by page basis (e.g. Blue Background, White Background, Large Logo etc).

If you'd like to have a series of options that are easy to adjust on the fly, you could set up some [Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and then adjust your template to pull settings from them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

First, define action like this:

function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );